Scrapy + Playwright: calling a synchronous parse_single function from an async parse function
I'm working with scrapy + Playwright.
A simplified version of the spider I have currently:
class MySpider(CodeSpider):
    def start_requests(self):
        url = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=product+designer+nyc&ibp=htl;jobs'
        yield Request(url, headers=headers, meta={
                    'playwright': True,
                    'playwright_include_page': True,
                    'errback': self.errback,
                })

    async def parse(self, response):
        page = response.meta["playwright_page"]
        jobs = page.locator("//li")
       
        num_jobs = await jobs.count()

        for idx in range(num_jobs):
            await jobs.nth(idx).click()
            job_details = page.locator("#tl_ditsc")
            
            job_details_html = await job_details.inner_html()
            soup = BeautifulSoup(job_details_html, 'html.parser')
            data = self.parse_single_jd(soup)

            yield {
                'idx': idx,
                'data': data,
            }

    def parse_single_jd(self, soup):
        print("parse_single_jd running!")
        title_of_role = soup.h2.text

        data = {
            "title": title_of_role,
        }
        return data

The spider runs - it opens a Playwright browser, navigates to the URL, and will loop thru the jobs on the page and click on each one.
However, it is NOT running the self.parse_single_jd function as expected - the data that's yielded ends up being a <generator object ... >. Indeed, the print("parse_single_jd running!") line never fires.
I suspect this has to do with running the synchronous parse_single_jd function from the async parse function. How do I force parse_single_jd to run / evaluate in this situation?

if it is real generator then you can use it with next(data)(to get first/next element) or for item in data: ... to work with all elements at once.

if it never runs print("parse_single_jd running!") them maybe it never runs for idx in range(num_jobs): - so maybe num_jobs is zero. Maybe  use more print() to see which part of code is really executed and what you have in all variables,

It is definitely running through the for idx in range() loop (I have more code than in the snippet above which confirms to me that it's at least iterating through the items in the range). To your first question - parse_single_jd returns a dictionary though, not an array. Does that change your advice?

I don't understand - do you get <generator object ... > or dictionary? If you get generator then try to use for-loop to see what you get - maybe it explain what can be the problem.

Unlike the code you posted your actual code has parse_single_jd as a generator function. Never post simplified code that removes the problem source.

Does this answer your question? What does the "yield" keyword do in Python?

The working version of this turned out to be pretty simple. Not sure if I had tried it before and it wasn't working for some other reason. But here's what I have now:
In parse(...):
  for idx in range(num_jobs):
    jd_to_yield = await self.parse_single_jd(soup_full, meta_info)
    ...
    yield jd_to_yield
  
  await page.close()  # This is important when using Playwright with Scrapy
  return

Then the other function looks like this:
async def parse_single_jd(self, soup, meta_info):
  ...
  return data

